# Adding javascript to header of MetroMagazine theme

Tags: plugins, javascript, scripts

I am currently working on http://cryptoportugal.com/ and I'm still starting on Wordpress and I got stuck trying to add a javascript script (widget) to my website header. The script is the following - https://www.cryptocompare.com/dev/widget/wizard/?type=6&theme=0&fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR,CNY,GBP

Currently using MetroMagazine theme and I've tried installing a plugin such as 'Header and Footer' but I'm only able to add it to the footer.

I just can't find a way to edit the header. Help would be extremely appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, can't you just simply add it to the `header.php` file in your template? Is there a restriction to do this?

Comment: @JackJohansson I've added it on the <head> section of header.php but still nothing shows up on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit theme files. Your changes will be overwritten when your theme updates.

Instead use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and hook into the wp_head function. Add this to your child theme's functions.php file.

```
function add_js() {
?>
    <script>
        Your JavaScript goes here
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_js');
```

BTW, as you have a commercial theme, you can also get support from your theme vendor.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into this and update tomorrow with any trouble that might arise!